# DataTable() not giving proper object reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to use jquery table by initializing the table like

```
$("#someTable").DataTable();
```

This is giving me the object reference which contains member methods like column, columns and others. Here `someTable` is a normal static table with columns specified in thead and few static rows.

I am trying to intialize other table which uses server side pagination and the columns are not specified in  tag but in datatable aoColumns. like

```
listDataTable= $("#ListDataPane_data").DataTable({
            "iDisplayLength":100, 
            "bFilter": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sServerMethod": "POST",
            "sAjaxSource": PaginationUrl,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bStateSave": true,
            "sScrollY":"300",

           "aaSorting":orderSort,
           "aoColumns": aoColumns,

             "bScrollInfinite": true,
             "sScrollY": "300px",
             "sScrollX": "963px",
             "bAutoWidth": false,
                            },
        });
var  aoColumns  =  [
                      { "sTitle": "Action","sWidth":"30px","sName": "Action","sClass":"column_action","bSortable":false},
                      { "sTitle": "","sWidth":"30px", "bSortable":false },
                      { "sTitle": " ","sWidth":"20px" , "bSortable":false},
                      { "sTitle": "Mode","sWidth":"100px" ,"sName": "orderType","bSearchable": true,"sClass":"column_pm","bSortable":true},
                      { "sTitle": "Provider","sWidth":"80px" ,"sName": "providerName","sClass":"column_action"},                                 
                      { "sTitle": "Id","sWidth":"80px","sName":"id","bSortable":true,"sClass":"column_orderid"},
                      { "sTitle": "Status" ,"sWidth":"100px","sName": "Status","sClass":"column_action"},
                      { "sTitle": "Validated By", "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": false ,"sWidth":"100px","sName": "validatedBy" , "bSortable":true,"sClass":"column_validated"},
                ];
```

This is giving response which doesnt contain column and columns properties. I need to access these properties. Someone has any solution?

Comment: Can you provide the value of `aoColumns`?

Comment: what properties are you looking to get?

Answer (score 1):

> **CAUSE**

There are some issues with your code:

- unnecessary closing bracket `}`
- `aoColumns` variable should be defined **before** you use it during DataTables initialization.
- trailing commas

> **SOLUTION**

The correct code is shown below

```
var  aoColumns = [
    { "sTitle": "Action","sWidth":"30px","sName": "Action","sClass":"column_action","bSortable":false},
    { "sTitle": "","sWidth":"30px", "bSortable":false },
    { "sTitle": " ","sWidth":"20px" , "bSortable":false},
    { "sTitle": "Mode","sWidth":"100px" ,"sName": "orderType","bSearchable": true,"sClass":"column_pm","bSortable":true},
    { "sTitle": "Provider","sWidth":"80px" ,"sName": "providerName","sClass":"column_action"},                                 
    { "sTitle": "Id","sWidth":"80px","sName":"id","bSortable":true,"sClass":"column_orderid"},
    { "sTitle": "Status" ,"sWidth":"100px","sName": "Status","sClass":"column_action"},
    { "sTitle": "Validated By", "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": false ,"sWidth":"100px","sName": "validatedBy" , "bSortable":true,"sClass":"column_validated"}
];

var listDataTable = $("#ListDataPane_data").DataTable({
  "iDisplayLength": 100,
  "bFilter": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sServerMethod": "POST",
  "sAjaxSource": PaginationUrl,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "bJQueryUI": false,
  "bDestroy": true,
  "bStateSave": true,
  "sScrollY": "300",
  "aaSorting": orderSort,
  "aoColumns": aoColumns,
  "bScrollInfinite": true,
  "sScrollY": "300px",
  "sScrollX": "963px",
  "bAutoWidth": false
});
```